# Can't runserver, ModuleNotFoundError[Django]

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to work with django, but I can't runserver it shows an error like this

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'music.apps. MusicConfig'; 'music.apps' is not a package"

**Note:** I'm using python3.

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Comment: What is the file structure of your project?

Comment: did you run migration command?

Comment: Did you add your app to installed_apps ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your music/apps directory doesn't contain `__init__.py` file. Create and empty one and `apps` will become a package